# add link to a module in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to get a list of opencart Attributes  and add in a link in the top menu to link to this module.There will be a single page display all Attributes list in order list when user click the link on the top menu.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally read the methods in the controller, model and library files to check if there is sth you can use. You could for instance use the `getAttributes` method in admin/model/catalog/attribute.php. This will give you all atrributes for the language you are using if you need all attributes independent of language write an new model file and copy this function there without the `WHERE` clauses:

```php
class simpleAttributeClass extends Model {

    public function getAttributes($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT agd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_group_description agd) AS attribute_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute a LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_description ad ON (a.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id)";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $result['rows'];
    }
}
```

Put this in `admin/model/catalog/simple_attribute.php`

Then create a file `admin/controller/catalog/simple_attribute.php` with the following content:

```php
class simpleAttributeClass extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('catalog/simple_attribute');
        $this->data['all_attributes'] = $this->model_catalog_simple_attribute->getAttributes();


        $this->template = 'catalog/attribute_list.tpl';
        $this->children = array(
        'common/header',
        'common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
}
```

and then create a `view/template/catalog/simple_attribute.tpl` file with eg:

```html
<ul>
<?php foreach ($all_attributes as $attribute) { ?>
<li><?php echo $attribute['name']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

For the link you want, edit the header.tpl file (or do it through vqmod) and add `<li><a href="index.php?route=catalog/simple_attribute">All attributes</a></li>`

I haven't tested that, so there might be some errors but it should give you the basic idea how you should work with opencart code.